# google app script : how to change folder destination

Tags: google-apps-script, subdirectory

I am using the script below to export a google spreadsheet to CSV (thank you ziganotschka).
I am trying to save the CSV in another folder than the same as my Spreadsheet.
I have a folder containing my spreadsheet and inside a subfolder ("Final_Export) where I would like the CSV to save in.

The app script I use is :

```
function saveAsCSV() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ssname = ss.getName();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); 
var folder = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents().next();
var fileName = ssname + ".csv";
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ss.getId() + "/export? 
exportFormat=csv&format=csv";  
var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();  
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + sheet.getSheetId(), {
headers: {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
}
});
folder.createFile(response.getBlob().setName(fileName));
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution.
I had this code :

```
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("myFolderDestinationId");
  var folder = parentFolder;
```

Comment: If the folder you want to use was the only subfolder then you could have used `folder.getFolders().next();` https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getFolders()

Comment: yes better, i use this :   var folder = DriveApp.getFolders().next(); instead of  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("myFolderDestinationId");
  var folder = parentFolder; thank you cooper